# Ionic APP_ID is "undefined" in .io-config.json

Tags: ionic-framework

Using Ionic 1.2.x I'm trying to setup notifications using Ionic's new cloud services, and I followed the very few [instructions](http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#installation) to install and configure it within the application, but then the docs say the app_id is in ionic.config.json, which it isn't.  So I looked in a new file .io-config.json, and I can see the "app_id" key has a value of "undefined", and then I have what looks like a proper api_key.  The app also doesn't get created in the Dashboard, which the docs say it should.

What do I do if there is no app_id value, and the Dashboard doesn't contain an application?  The new Cloud services docs definitely don't appear to be up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you need to run `ionic login` in your terminal, and then follow the setup instructions by running `ionic io init`.

Comment: If .io-config.json is missing in the build, could this cause push notifications not to work?